# Passing different payloads to same component

Tags: reactjs

I have one button that when you click you generate a number and i want to pass different numbers to two dices.

```
import { GENERATE_NUMBER } from './types';
import generateDiceNumber from '../util/DiceNumber';
export const generateNumber = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    const result = generateDiceNumber();
    console.log(result);
    return dispatch({
      type: GENERATE_NUMBER,
      payload: result
    });
  };
};
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { generateNumber } from '../../actions/diceActions';

class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log('PROPS' + JSON.stringify(this.props));
    console.log('playerNumber' + this.props.playerNumber);
    console.log('cpuNumber' + this.props.cpuNumber);

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.playerNumber}</div>
        <div>{this.props.cpuNumber}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Button.propTypes = {
  generateNumber: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  playerNumber: state.playerNumber,
  cpuNumber: state.cpuNumber,
  number: state.number
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  generateNumber
})(Button);
```

My Two dices get the same result from generateDiceNumber and i want both dices to generate a random number, equal or not.

Whats the best structure to achiev this?

```
return dispatch({
      type: SAVE_PLAYER_NUMBER,
      payload: {
I'd: 1,
num: x
}
    })
```

Should i have an id for each Dice?

Any help please? Im blocked.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to achieve this, is to simply make the GENERATE_NUMBER action have an array of two random numbers as a payload.
Something along the lines of

```
export const generateNumber = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    const result = [generateDiceNumber(), generateDiceNumber()];
    console.log(result);
    return dispatch({
      type: GENERATE_NUMBER,
      payload: result
    });
  };
};
```